# How to create objects based on user input?

Tags: c++, class, object, oop

I want to make a program which creates an object each time user enters an employee name. The object should be named according to the name of the employee.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class employee
  {
    public:
    
    int salary;
    int  ma = 300;
    float da = 1.25;
    float hra = 0.15;
    
  };
int main()
{
  char name;
  cin >> name;
  employee:("name");
}
```

How can do this?
using this piece of code throws an error

```
main.cpp:18:13: warning: expression result unused
      [-Wunused-value]
  employee:("name");
            ^~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: You cannot dynamically create variable names. What you could do instead is have an `std::unordered_map<std::string, employee>` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `employee` class a `name` field, and a constructor to initialize it

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
public:
    string name;
    int salary = 0;
    int ma = 300;
    float da = 1.25;
    float hra = 0.15;

    employee(string name) : name(name) {}
};

int main()
{
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    employee emp(name);
}
```

Comment: How do i add value in salary attribute of the object created according to the input of the user?

Comment: @DeepjyotiPurkayastha declare a variable, read into it from `cin` same as you do with `name`, and then assign the variable to `emp.salary`. And then get yourself some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/), because this is fundamental stuff that every book/tutorial covers.